# Doing more than one atomic operations on shared variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, concurrency, boost-thread

I want to do two operations on a shared variable. I need to guarantee that it can be done atomically. Can some one help me clarify if the following approach is correct:

```
#include <atomic>
std::atomic<int> index;

void function()
{
     // I need the variable index to be incremented but bound in the 
     // range of [0,9].
     int loc_indx = index.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
     index.store( (loc_indx+1)%10  , std::memory_order_release);
}
```

Based on my understanding, the index store operation and index load operation have to happen together. Can some of the experts here clarify if the above code will be equivalent to the following pseudo-code:

```
ATOMIC
{
   index = (index+1)%10;
}
```

I have been working with atomic package in c++ part of Visual Studio 2012 or/and boost::atomic part of 1.53.

Comment: Are all threads accessing `index` by calling `function()`? Or are they free to access `index` however they want?

Comment: The increment can be done only by calling `function()` by all threads. Yes there are more threads accessing `function()` at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole purpose of atomics is to improve performance compared to locks.

There are no locks in your code. The `memory_order` enum is just to make sure that the compiler does not reorder the code (nor let the CPU reorder it). This means there is a small chance that some other thread modifies the value between `load` and `store`. If the stored value must depend on the previous value, then the calculations done in between are wasted and need to be redone. Doing this can be considerably more efficient than locks since the chance that the concurrent modification does actually occur is low, and the calculations are cheap and simple.

Store when you know the previous value, otherwise recalculate and retry. Something like:

```
 int loc_index = index.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
 int desired = (loc_index+1)%10;

 while ( !index.compare_exchange_strong( loc_index, desired ) )
 {
     desired = (loc_index+1)%10;
 }
```

`compare_exchange_strong` is atomic operation that compares the value stored in `index` to `loc_index`; if they are equal, it stores `desired` into `index`; if they are not equal, it copies the value of `index` into `loc_index`. That helps you to make sure that the next
value stored in `index` is correct one.

Comment: You are missing `(` on line 4 (starting from 1:-)).

Comment: If you could add some explanation, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @goutham - the call to `compare_exchange_strong` compares the value stored in `index` to `loc_index`; if they are equal, it stores `desired` into `index`; if they are not equal, it copies the value of `index` into `loc_index`. All this is done atomically. In the first case it returns true, in the second case it returns false. Pretty dense, isn't it? `<g>`. (Running out of space; see next comment)

Comment: @goutham - (continued from previous comment) -  In essence, it keeps loading a new value from `index`, incrementing its value, and storing the result into `desired`. Then it checks whether the value in `index` has changed since it last loaded it; if not, it stores `desired` into `index` and exits the loop. On the other hand, if the value changed, then some other thread did the update in the middle of this thread's work, so it has to try again, using the new value of `index`.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thanks for answering my question. Just a trivial correction. I had to move `int desired` declaration outside the `do .. while` loop to fix a variable out of scope error.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for clarifying my answer, I was too sleepy so I left. goutham: yes, fixed that do.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. It would be nice, though, if you could add a few words about the original code given in the question (which I think cannot be used for this purpose).

Comment: @jogojapan Good idea! I added some text to discuss the background. Hopefully it explains why OP code was too naive.